# Is there any way rather than assigning functions to modules?

Tags: python, function, module, computer-science

I found this definition of modules in Python:

> "Structures that contain functions or properties, in which we can declare variables."

Don't we need to assign functions to modules every time, or is there any way rather than assigning functions?

Comment: Is your question 'can a function exist somewhere other than a module?' or 'can I have a module without assigning functions?'

Comment: I think that somewhat obscure (while not strictly incorrect) definition is confusing you a bit. The usual way to "assign functions to modules" is to define the module with a `.py` file, and use `def` statements inside the file to "assign" the function to a name. Modules are part of the normal operation of Python. You don't need to jump through hoops to use them.

Comment: yeah my question was "can I have a module without assigning functions?". But thank u sm 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Python docs I think we can update the definition just a little: *A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements*

So you don't really need to have a function in a module if you don't want :)

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: No problem. I have seen python files with only variables (or constants, really) defined in them ... these are no doubt modules too even though very simple ones.